# the transactions are not rolling back in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
var mongo = require("mongoose")
session10 = await mongo.startSession
 try {
        
        await session10.withTransaction(async () => {
            console.log("transaction started");
        await readonlymodel.findOneAndUpdate({}, {
            $set: {
                readonlyMode: true,
                yearEndClosure: true
            }
        }, { session:session10 });
        var archivalActivity = {
            activity_id: 4,
            activityName: 'Current year Data Back',
            activity_Status: 'In Progress',
            err_occured: 'None',
            remarks: 'None'
        }
        await year_end_closure_model.findOneAndUpdate({ year: MCpayload.year, month: MCpayload.month, 'activities.activity_id': 3 }, {
            $set: {
                'activities.$.activity_Status': 'Completed',
            },
    
        }, { session:session10 });
        await year_end_closure_model.findOneAndUpdate({ year: MCpayload.year, month: MCpayload.month }, {
            $push: {
                activities: archivalActivity
            }
        }, {session: session10 })
 const dataCurrentYear = await model.find({}, { _id: 0 }, {session: session10 })
        const etBackupData = await archival_yearEnd.insertMany(etdataCurrentYear, {session: session10 });
        console.log(dataCurrentYear.length, etBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
        const etproofCurrentYear = await proofmodel.find({}, { _id: 0 }, { session: session10 });
        const proofBackupData = await proof_archival_yearEnd.insertMany(proofCurrentYear, { session:session10 });
        console.log(proofCurrentYear.length, proofBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
        const proofCurrentYear = await commonproofmodel.find({}, { _id: 0 }, {session: session10 });
        const proofBackupData = await common_proof_archival_yearEnd.insertMany(proofCurrentYear, { session:session10 });
        console.log(cmnproofCurrentYear.length, cmnproofBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
        const etcaseCurrentYear = await etcasemodel.find({}, { _id: 0 }, {session: session10 });
        const etcaseBackupData = await caseStudy_proof_archival_yearEnd.insertMany(etcaseCurrentYear, {session: session10 });
        console.log(etcaseCurrentYear.length, etcaseBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
        const SummaryCurrentYear = await summary_model.find({}, { _id: 0 }, {session: session10 });
        const SummaryBackupData = await Summary_archive_yearEnd.insertMany(SummaryCurrentYear, {session: session10 });
        console.log(SummaryCurrentYear.length, SummaryBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
        const DetailsCurrentYear = await data_model.find({}, { _id: 0 }, { session:session10 });
        const DetailsBackupData = await Detail_archive_yearEnd.insertMany(DetailsCurrentYear, {session: session10 });
        console.log(DetailsCurrentYear.length, DetailsBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
        const ExpCurrentYear = await umt_exception_model.find({}, { _id: 0 }, {session:session10 });
        const ExpBackupData = await UmtExceptional_archive_yearEnd.insertMany(ExpCurrentYear, {session: session10 });
        console.log(ExpCurrentYear.length, ExpBackupData.length, "inserted Succesfully")
    

more operations to do//
return true
}catch(err){
console.log(err)
}finally{
session10.endSession()
}
```

I have used mongoose to start the session, and let me know incase I did something wrong.

if anything in transaction is failing, it's not reverting back, please let me know where I have done mistake, and I am running this in batchjob.The transaction is running and roll backing correctly in case of error but it is starting another transaction after 1 minute and it is executing the same operations again resulting in a "[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'TransientTransactionError' }" error

Comment: If it's still the issue for you, you should simplify your code: *. Remove everything unrelated to transaction logic itself. *. Remove all operations except of the single one. *. So, If you claim that `aborttransaction` doesn't work for you, then do only steps like: 1. Create session and transaction. 2. Run `insertMany`/`findOneAndUpdate` with configured session. 3. Direct call for AbortTransaction. 4. Check that data is not reverted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call [AbortTransaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Session.abortTransaction/). However, mongo provides convenient `withTransaction` API that will simplify this work for you. See [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.5/classes/ClientSession.html#withTransaction). See also mongoose related [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html).

Comment: I have added it in code, are you saying me to remove it... even after adding it's doing the same it's not reverting back the previous operations before error.. please let me know

Comment: the code you provided doesn't have it. And also I'm saying that there is a built in helper (`withtransaction`) in API that may simplify your code

Comment: can you help me out by giving an example by using withTransaction. don't we need to use abort transaction in it. please let me know for above code

Comment: no, aborttransaction as well as committransaction and advanced exception handling will happen automatically

Comment: it's not rolling back by using withTransaction also, if i include any function which doesn't include session, will it have any problem?

Comment: I vote that you're doing something weird and incorrect, check my comment to your question and implement a simple few lines code example where you directly call AbortTransaction and if it works add logic step by step as in your question

Comment: ` if i include any function which doesn't include session, will it have any problem?` - you should always provide a session to driver's functions

Comment: I have tried using withtransaction as you suggested, and it is rolling back as you mentioned which is really great!!!, but found another issue with withTransaction, the query is running again and again before completion of one transaction, it is running another and giving error like "transaction 2 is aborted" .. It would be better if you guide me

Comment: you should provide an example of what you're doing

Comment: I have edited the example as you mentioned...

Comment: Transient transaction errors indicate it is safe to retry the transaction, so withTransaction does that for you.

Comment: if this error happens in `withTransaction` method, then this error should be already automatically retried. If it's still there, then it's exceeded some retry limits